# How to refresh the page between window widths 480px to 768px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I am currently using the code:

```
// Resize when less than 768
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {   
      location.reload();  // refresh page 
    }
    else {  
      // Width greater than 768px for PC  
    }
}); 
});
```

But this reloads the page constantly when the browser is resized less than 768px. Is it possible to have a code that only reloads the page on resize when the browser is say, between 480px and 768px? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course:

```
// Resize when less than 768
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if (($(window).width() > 480) && ($(window).width() < 768)) {   
      location.reload();  // refresh page 
    }
    else {  
      // Width greater than 768px for PC 
      // Or width is smaller than 480 for mobile
    }
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find a solution about this one, when I saw the accepted answer..

Please be carefull with your words mate:

> But this reloads the page constantly when the browser is resized less
>   than 768px.

The keyword *constantly* is misleading, making others to believe that the problem is the constant refreshing of the page, and not the limitation of the conditional.

Anyway, for those poor fellows who thought the problem is the constant renewing, here is a [**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gmanou/kLt9Lc0o/) of my humble solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Set flag refresh to true
    var refresh = true;
    //If the window width is between wanted limit set flag to false. This is needed for the resize*.
    if (($(window).width() > 480) && ($(window).width() < 768)) {
      refresh = false;
    }
    $(window).resize( function(){
    /* When resize hits limits check if flag is true, then refresh.
    Flag is set to false from above*, after refresh.
    Time is needed for the page to load and set the flag to false.
    Otherwise flag is not updated and constant refresh keeps happening while resizing. */
    if (($(window).width() > 480) && ($(window).width() < 768) ) {
      if (refresh == true) location.reload();
    } else {
        refresh = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable when the page first loads (in the `ready()` handler) that checks the initial size of the window. Then only use the resize event if necessary.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var initialSize = $(window).width();

    //don't resize on small sizes
    if (initialSize < 768) { return; }

    //otherwise continue
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 768 && ) {   
          location.reload();  // refresh page 
        }
        else {  
           // Width greater than 768px for PC  
        }
    }); 
});
```